# How to convert current time from a specific format to epoch time in python?

Tags: python, epoch

My current time format is in "Wednesday, November 16, 2022 4:21:33.082 PM GMT+05:30" format.

How can I convert this to epoch time using python?

Here in this case the epoch time should be "1668595893082"

**Note: I always want to get my current time format in the above format and then convert that to epoch.**

Please guide me.

I tried using strftime('%s') but could not get the solution. Its throwing invalid format exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime

dt_string = "Wednesday, November 16, 2022 4:21:33.082 PM GMT+05:30"
dt_format = '%A, %B %d, %Y %I:%M:%S.%f %p GMT%z'
datetime.strptime(dt_string, dt_format).timestamp() * 1_000
```

See [datetime: strftime() and strptime() Format Codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) and [datetime: datetime.timestamp()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp)

Answer (score 1):

I have used [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/parser.html) in the past, it can parse textual dates into `datetime.datetime` objects (from [the inbuilt `datetime` package](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects))

First you need to install it:

`pip install python-dateutil`

Then you can use it like so:

```py
from dateutil import parser

# extract datetime object from string
dttm = parser.parse('Wednesday, November 16, 2022 4:21:33.082 PM GMT+05:30')

# convert to unix time
print(dttm.timestamp())

>>> 1668635493.082
```